# How to create an Adminhtml page with grid table getting data from custom MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using Magento 1.9.0.1.

Right now i'm working on a custom extension for Magento and i need to know how to get the data from a custom MySQL table into a table in custom admin panel page.

I've already added a custom page in the admin panel, here it is:

[image]

Here is the code of this page /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/vivasindustries/smsnotification/about.phtml:

```
<h2> Hi there</h2>
This is new custom page where i must add a grid table!
```

In this page i want to add a grid table like this one:

[image]

This is just an example of what kind of table i need.
In this table there must be in first time so i can understand how the things work only 3 cells - `Receiver`,`Phone` and `Date` which is fetching data from my custom MySQL table `VivasIndustries_SmsNotification`.

Here is a picture from the phpMyAdmin so you can see the structure of the table `VivasIndustries_SmsNotification`:

[image]

So at final i want to say that i want this data to be snown in my custom admin page a grid table..

Please help me out to make this thing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a grid container and the grid itself (For an example see Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order and Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid). The important method for your case is _prepareCollection in the grid class. That's the place where you have to build your query for fetching the data. Furthermore you have to define the columns of the grid in _prepareColumns method. The index-field of the array passed to addColumn must be a index of the collection. 
I assume that you have created the model, resource model and collection model for accessing the data from the database. One last thing is to create a layout handle in order to add the grid container to the layout.

Comment: Can you please give me any link to a guide for this? Thanks!

Comment: Of course: https://markshust.com/2012/07/05/creating-magento-adminhtml-grids-simplified